# same input for interactive command in Perl script

Tags: perl, cmd

In Perl script I am using command of unit(external command) using system
but that command need some run time input from user. Every time I want to give similar input which is stored in variable.

My command is:

```
system("dt ci $dest_file");
```

after this command my script is waiting for user input,
lets say I want to give "re base" as input to this every time

How can I give fix input every time it asks?

Please help, I am working on windows 7.

I want to make script completely automated... it should not wait for user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your script like this:

```
perl test.pl < input.txt
```

It should take the content of the file as an input. ( this is working with STDIN read )

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..... instead of having file for just one word "rebase" can i have some variable in script itsef and give value of that to cmd?

Comment: Yea it depends on the way you want to automate it :)

Comment: Hmm what is your script doing in first place some complex logic or it just tries to execute a command which requires user input

Comment: some complex logic... it is checking out files modifying and again cheking in that file.... so while checking in it asks for user input

Comment: with above your fix it is giving me warning "use of uninitialized value in pattern match<m//>"

Comment: If the script ends and is run again will it continue or it will cause problem ?

Comment: Does it need this user input once only ?

Comment: no commed is executed in while loop so every time the command will execute it will need ser input.... but we can give sinilar input everytime

Comment: No i mean is the command within the loop ( which i suppose is endless with some timer at the end ? ) which requires the input only one ?

Comment: Why don't you remove the loop and shedule the script in Task Sheduler ( on Windows ) and make it recieve the input from a file like I said or just ' perl scrip.pl < rebase ' should also work. This way you won't need your scrip to be running non stop which i suppose also can cause problems.

Comment: perl scrip.pl < rebase giving error as system cannot find path specified:(

Comment: because your scrip isn't located under the default directory which when you open CMD you can see i suppose it should be eighter C:\Windows or C:\Users\....\.   There is a field ' Start in'